# What is the difference between role=dialog and role=alertdialog?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

According to the [WAI-ARIA specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/) both roles should have:

- Focus on first focusable element
- User should not be able to leave dialog
- Should have proper `aria-label` set
- Should be used to interrupt flow and should require to take some action e.g. to click a button or to type something

The only difference I see is that `alertdialog` should have `aria-describedby` set.

This leads me to a question. Whats the practical difference between `role=dialog` and `role=alertdialog`? When shall we use one or another?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_alertdialog_role), alertdialog is a subtype of dialog.

What differentiate them is their role. As the name implies, alertdialogs should be used when the context requires the user's immediate attention (i.e in case of alerts, warnings or errors).

**edit**: corrected the explanation thanks to @cjl750 comment.

Comment: You linked the right thing, but I think you're drawing attention to the wrong details. The  one focusable control thing differentiates alert dialogs from regular alerts. The difference between alert dialogs and other dialogs is mentioned in the paragraph right below the three bullets. Would suggest an edit to this answer.

Comment: You are right, I totally misread that. Thanks for pointing it out.